# Is Redshift Application Tracking Our Locations? Or Am I Wrong? What is that means in 'Location' that i have attached in the screen shot?

Tags: redshift, night-light

[Redshift Application Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAVSx.png)

I'm not sure what is that means "Location" in info on Redshift Application. Don't know much about Linux applications. This is why i'm asking from you guys. i'm very appreciate if someone can  help with my question, thank you.

Comment: You can also get your longitude and latitude and manually type it in for your location as well.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift location needs to know your location on Earth in order to do its job.

It's right there in plain language in very first sentence of the [project documentation](http://jonls.dk/redshift/).

> Project description
>
> Redshift adjusts the color temperature according to the position of the sun.

Since most folks don't carry a sextant, redshift uses your location and the current time to calculate the position of the sun.

It's not transmitting your location to some secret cabal.

The purpose of the "Location" field is for you to manually enter latitude/longitude in case the GeoClue automatic location service fails. See https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/master/redshift.conf.sample